# Generate censored data in R for given percentage

Tags: r, survival-analysis, exponential, reliability, weibull

I want to generate `10%, 20%` and `30%` censored data in `R`using the following two distributions.

```
# generate the life-time observations
data1 = c(rweibull(15, 1,2), rweibull(35, 2,3))
# censoring time observations
data2 = rexp(50, c)
```

But I want to determine the `c`  by the given censoring proportion, for example,  `10%, 20%` and `30%`. That is, we can calculate by `P(data1 >= data2) = 10%`,  `P(data1 >= data2) = 20%` and so on. My question is how to find `c` for a given proportion? Do we have any specific `r` functions? Thank you!

Comment: In statistical terms you are asking for analytical solutions to the intersection of the cumulative distributions of a mixture of Weibulls and an exponential. It seems extremely unlikely that a simple solution could be constructed, but there is a package that lets you do high-level operations with distributions. Install the `distr` package and then work through the vignette. It labels itself as "Object Oriented Implementation of Distributions" and it's a great way to get experience with the behavior of statistical distributions. It's like an instant upper level mathematical statistics course.

Comment: Did you seek other opinions? I found an interesting discussion of power transformed exponential distributions. Turns out they are Weibull. You could apply a power transformation to an exponential to make its 0.7 quantile the same as that of your random realization of the unbalanced mixture of Weibulls. https://actuarialmodelingtopics.wordpress.com/2017/06/10/transformed-exponential-distributions/